# Windows doesn't detect virtualization

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, intel-haxm

**CPU:** Intel Core i3 3220

---

**Motherboard:** P8B75-M LX (BIOS version: 1403, final)

---

**OS:** Windows 10 Education 64-bit

---

**Note:** I have screenshots including BIOS settings but I can't add because of reputation points.

I set virtualization option from BIOS settings.
Advanced \ CPU Configuration \ Intel Virtualization Technology enabled.

After that, even if I shutdown and re-launch the PC, the system doesn't detect virtualization (Piriform Speccy > Virtualization: Supported, Disabled) and I got:

> *This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on. HAXM cannot be
>   installed until VT-x is enabled. Please refer to the Intel HAXM
>   documentation for more information.*

error when I try to install "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager".

Comment: Hi Kowen. Please [edit] your question to add *a specific question* that we can answer. As it stands, all I see are statements of fact. As for screenshots, post them anywhere and include a URL, and if they are legitimate, someone with the necessary reputation will edit them in.

Comment: Is this what you look for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748754/haxm-error-but-vt-x-is-enabled

Comment: Thank you, _aldwinaldwin_. That was all because of **Avast**, _disabling "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting_ and rebooting after that solved the problem.